# How to create object with many to many field?

Tags: python, tortoise-orm

I have a DB structure

```
from tortoise.models import Model


class Company(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    users: fields.ManyToManyRelation[User] = fields.ManyToManyField(
        "models.User",
        related_name="companies",
        through="company_team",
        index=True,
    )
```

I want to create a Company object
I am trying like this

```
async def create_company(
        self,
        user: User):

    company = await core.Company.create(user_id=user.id)
```

Is it correct way? What if I want to set several users for the company?